# How to call function inside function through only HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, call

I just can't reach the function inside function using only HTML.
**How to call setLayout() using only HTML** or is it able to call only in Javascript?

```
<button onclick="customize.setLayout('b.html');">Click Please</button>
```

Javascript:

```
 function customize() {
     function setLayout(text) {

        var selectedLayout = text;
        layout += selectedLayout;
        $.get(layout, function (data) {
            $("#layout-grid").html(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thats wrong. remove customize

Comment: I don't understand. you call "customize" with a paremeter even though it doesn't take a parameter, and it never get passed to "setLayout".

Comment: You should never construct a function inside of a function.

Comment: Please spellcheck your question title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't possible to call `setLayout` at all.

Functions defined in other functions are scoped to that function. They can only be called by other code from within that scope.

If you want to to be able to call `customize.setLayout` then you must first create `customize` (which can be a function, but doesn't need to be) then you need to make `setLayout` a property of that object.

```
customize.setLayout = function setLayout(text) { /* yada yada */ };
```

Answer (score 4):

Multiple ways to call a function within a function. First of all, the inner function isn't visible to the outside until you explicitly expose it Just one way would be:

```
function outerobj() {

    this.innerfunc = function () { alert("hello world"); }

}
```

This defines an object but currently has no instance. You need to create one first:

```
var o = new outerobj();
o.innerfunc();
```

Another approach:

```
var outerobj = {

    innerfunc : function () { alert("hello world"); }

};
```

This would define an object `outerobj` which can be used immediately:

```
outerobj.innerfunc();
```

Comment: This won't work at all, as a five-second console test would show. Your "another approach" is not even valid JS syntax.

Comment: @torazaburo oops yes, just changed the syntax

Answer (score 2):

> Simple answer: **You can't call `setLayout()` with this setup anywhere!**

The reason being, `setLayout()` will not be visible outside of `customize()` not even from other `JavaScript` code because it is defined locally inside `customize()` so it has local scope which is only available inside `customize()`. Like others have mentioned there are other ways possible... (^__^)

You can return the response of `setLayout()` by returning it as a method of `customize()` and use it in your `HTML` like `customize().setLayout('b.html');` e.g.

```
<button onclick="customize().setLayout('b.html');">Click Please</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function customize() {

    var setLayout = function (text) {
        var selectedLayout = text;
        layout += selectedLayout;
        $.get(layout, function (data) {
            $("#layout-grid").html(data);
        });
    };

    return {
        setLayout: setLayout
    };

}
```

---

### Another Approach

You can also define your main function i.e. `customize` as [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). This way you can omit the parenthesis while calling its method in `HTML` section.

```
<button onclick="customize.setLayout('b.html');">Click Please</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var customize = (function () {

    var setLayout = function (text) {
        var selectedLayout = text;
        layout += selectedLayout;
        $.get(layout, function (data) {
            $("#layout-grid").html(data);
        });
    };

    return {
        setLayout: setLayout
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

if you insist to do it this way, maybe define setLayout and then call it,
something like this:

```js
<script>
  function customize(text, CallSetLayout) {
    if (CallSetLayout) {
      (function setLayout(text) {
        //do something
        alert(text);
      })(text);
    }
  }

</script>
```

```html
<button onclick="customize('sometext',true);">Click Please</button>
```

then you can decide if you even want to define and call setLayout from outside

Comment: Well, this works and this is interesting. I am seeking to know more, why there are "()" surrounding function setLayout() and "(text);" after the end . Is it some sort of defining function ?. I just can't understand how to read it.

Comment: @Mes, this thing is called a "closure", a function that is defined and than executes itself. it is very commonly used when defining modules in javascript. the (text) after the definition is exactly the invocation of the function with "text" as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat it as object and method

```
<button onclick="customize().setLayout('b.html');">Click Please</button>
```

Sorry I had to edit this code for more clarification

```
function customize() {

     this.setLayout = function setLayout(text) {

        var selectedLayout = text;
        layout += selectedLayout;
        $.get(layout, function (data) {
            $("#layout-grid").html(data);
        });
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Please test your suggestions before posting. This won't work at all.

Comment: Please try this solution